# minted with Texmaker on OS X

Tags: texmaker, minted, mac, pygments

I'm trying to use minted with texmaker. The weird thing is, that it works, when I invoke

```
pdflatex --shell-escape testfile
```

in the system shell, but not from texmaker, though *Options -> Configure TeXmaker | PdfLaTeX* says

```
"/usr/texbin/pdflatex" -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex
```

Main difference in the logs:

From shell

```
/Users/tmartin/anaconda/bin/pygmentize
```

is called.

texmaker tries to call

```
/usr/local/bin/pygmentize
```

Why are different versions of pygmentize called and how can i fix this?

Comment: You should know why you have different versions of `pygmentize`.

Comment: @egreg: This comment isn't helpful at all. It doesn't matter if there are several versions installed. The question is: Why are different versions CALLED? What shell is texmaker using and why should there be a difference in `$PATH`.

Comment: That depends on how you set the `PATH` variable.

Comment: Does `/usr/local/bin/pygmentize` exist or not?

Comment: The [Texmaker Changelog](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/log.html) mentions some path-related changes. According to that, versions from 3.5.1 on allow adding directories to the system path.

Comment: Possibly helpful: [Setting environment variables in OS X for GUI applications](http://superuser.com/questions/476752)

Answer (score 2):

You could try to create a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) as a workaround:

```
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo ln -s /Users/tmartin/anaconda/bin/pygmentize pygmentize
```

Now you have a link `pygmentize` within `/usr/local/bin` that points to `~/anaconda/bin/pygmentize`. As a result, Texmaker should call the same `pygmentize` installation that is used in your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The other answer also works, but a perhaps more elegant solution (for example for those who cannot use `sudo`), is to add your `anaconda/bin/` to texmaker's PATH, which you can do at the bottom of the "Commands" page of texmaker's settings.