# Texmaker Minted Error: You must have pygmentize installed

Tags: texmaker, minted, pygments

I know there are a lot of similar questions out there, but sadly I wasn't able to solve my problem with any of the given answers.

I am using Texmaker on a company owned Laptop running Windows 10.

I installed python and TexMaker from our company-managed app store.

I installed minted using `pip` and also added the location, where my pygmentize.exe is located, to PATH.

My current situation is, that I can run `pdflatex --shell-escape myfile.tex` from cmd and it compiles just fine.

If I however want to compile my file from TexMaker directly I get the following Error:

> Package minted Error: You must have pygmentize installed to use this package

This is what my PDFLaTeX command looks like in TexMaker:

> pdflatex -synctex=1 -shell-escape -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

I also followed [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/524906/270238) and entered the location of my pygmentize.exe into the corresponding text field, but it also didn't help.
[image: Screenshot of my TexMaker settings]

I would be very happy if someone could help me with my problem.

**Edit:**

I initally wanted to write a detailed explanation of my steps and show when it does and doesn't work but I just can't get consistent results.

From an empty folder I have to compile and restart a differing number of times until it suddenly works.

I will try to test this further on Monday, but I don't know if this Testing is even valid, because for me the only way to get to a consistent state, is to clean up my working directory.

If there are other places where texmaker is storing information, it might be good to know them, to try and replicate the issue consistently.

Comment: Presumably pygmenize is not in the PATH of the shell from which you started the editor. If that is from a desktop icon, you may need to log out and log in again after changing the settings.

Comment: I started TexMaker from the start menu, but also have restarted my PC several times in attempting to solve this issue. I also thought about the problem of different shells; Maybe TexMaker is using a different shell to execute its commands. Is there any documentation regarding this topic?

Comment: the answer you linked to suggests you can set the path within the editor settings, Perhaps you should show your settings. I do not have texmaker or a windows tex, so can not help more.

Comment: Thanks, I added a screenshot of my settings, I would guess the most important field is  the one at the bottom saying: Add  to path variable

Comment: As I half suspected, you have the PATH wrong, should be the folder not the executable so end `\Scripts`

Comment: I thought I tried that before, but apparently I didn't. It is working now, thank you.

Comment: Ok, I don't know what is going on here. I tried to compile my file again this afternoon after activating the option to output to subfolder "Buid". I once again got the minted error. I tried to compile in Powershell, it didn't work, although im able to call `pygmentize -V`. But it was still working in cmd.